# Style EditText in Android Library

Tags: android, android-theme, android-library

I've created a Android library project with a custom prompt dialog.
Therefore I used the normal EditText Widget. 
But it is not styled as it should on an Android 5 device...

As you can see in the screenshot it is only the basic old Android Theme (orange border).

[Custom Dialog Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkFYS.png)

The EditText:

```
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text_input"/>
```

Also tried it with style="@style/AppTheme" -> still same.

My styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

Also tried to add style attribute in my AndroidManifest.xml but I dont think that this will work in a library project (so still same orange border ...)

Next thing I tried...
Created a custom EditText View:

```
public class MaterialEditText extends EditText {

public MaterialEditText(Context context) {
    super(context, null, R.style.Widget_AppCompat_EditText);
}

public MaterialEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs, R.style.Widget_AppCompat_EditText);
}
}
```

-> no EditText is shown if I click on it I see the value of the EditText but I can't edit it.

How can I solve this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem. This would include the Java code for creating the dialog, along with the layout resource that you used (if you used one).

Comment: And could you show us your style.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can't fix it I use a drawable to simulate material style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@+id/border_bottom">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#2196f3" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- main color -->
<item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#FAFBFB" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- draw another block to cut-off the left and right bars (holo -> 5dp) -->
<item android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#FAFBFB" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically a solution is to change the style attribute in your manifest.

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

For some reason you have to change the style to default in order to get another style libs to work.

Just try out the different styles by pressing "Alt + Space" in between the quotes of that attribute.